# Example/Demonstration of Quotient group $G/ H$ of Free Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $G$ be a free abelian group of rank $r$, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $G/ H$ is finite if and only if the ranks of $G$ and $H$ are equal.
If this is the case, and if $G$ and $H$ have $\Bbb Z$-bases $x_1, \cdots , x_r$ and $y_1,\cdots , y_r$
with $y_i=\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$, then $|G/H|=|\det(a_{ij})|$

Can anyone show an example or demonstration of above Theorem for free Abelian group  $G$, subgroup $H$, quotient group  $G/ H$?

In the book, it is written that ,

> for example, if $G$ has rank $3$ and $\Bbb Z$-basis $x, y, z$; and if $H$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis
> $$3x+y-2z,
> 4x-5y+ z,
> x +7z,$$
> then $|G/ H|$ is the absolute value of
> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 1 & -2\\
> 4 & -5 & 1\\
> 1 & 0 & 7
> \end{bmatrix}$,
> namely 142.

but in this case  what is quotient group $G/H$? What are the elements of quotient group $G/H$?

I am having trouble to visualize how would  $G/H$ look when $G$ and $H$ have $\Bbb Z$-bases $x_1, \cdots , x_r$ and $y_1,\cdots , y_r$ with $y_i=\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$.

This is Theorem Theorem 1.1 7. in the book Algebraic-Number Theory by Ian Stewart and David Tall, on page 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch**:

The general proof uses the *Fundamental structure theorem* for finitely generated abelian groups (which has a generalisation for finitely generated modules over a P.I.D.).

This theorem asserts that a subgroup $H$ of a finitely generated free abelian group $G$  of rank $r$ is free of rank $s\le r$, and that furthermore, there exists a basis $(x_1,\dots, x_r)$ and integers $(d_1,\dots, d_s)$ such that

- $(d_1x_1, \dots, d_s x_s)$ is a basis of $H$;
- $d_1\mid d_2\mid\dots\mid d_s.\,$ The $d_i$s are the *invariant factors* of the quotient $G/H$.

If $G$ and $H$  have the same rank, i.e. if $s=r$,  in the new basis, the matrix $A=\bigl(a_{ij}\bigr)$ becomes the diagonal matrix $D=\bigl(d_i\bigr)$, and the  change of basis matrix is  in $SL(\mathbf Z)$, so that
$\det(a_{ij})=\det D(d_i)=d_1\dots d_r$.

Now from the new basis, we deduce instantly that
$$G/H\simeq\Bbb Z^r\big/(d_1\mathbf Z\times\dots\times\mathbf Z/d_r\mathbf Z)
\simeq (\mathbf Z/d_1\mathbf Z)\times\dots \times (\mathbf Z/d_r\mathbf Z),$$
whence the assertion  for $|G/H|$.

Comment: for example, if $G$ has rank $2$ and $\Bbb Z$-basis $x, y$; and if $H$ has $\Bbb Z$-basis
$$2x+y,
x+3y$$
then what are the elements of $G/ H$ ? or how can one find these elements?

Comment: To have an explicit list of elements, you need to find the invariant factors and the adapted basis. This is obtained vy the algorithm to find the *Smith normal form* of this matrix. A priori, we know it will have 5elemenst (hence it will be cyclic and the invariant factors will be $(1,5)$).

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original question, before the edit.

The easiest example is if $r=1$, $G=\Bbb{Z}, H=2\Bbb{Z}$. The index is $2$, $G=\langle 1\rangle, H=\langle 2\rangle$, $2=2\cdot 1$ so the matrix is $(2)$ and the det is $2=|G:H|$. Less easy example is $G=\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}=\langle (1,0),(0,1)\rangle$,
$H=\langle (a,b),(c,d)\rangle$. Then $H$ has rank 2 iff $(a,b), (c,d)$ are not parallel. In that case the index $|G:H|$ is the area of the parallelogram spanned by $(a,b), (c,d)$ which is the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: in which book or notes have these examples/ also can you plz address the example I used? thanks.

Comment: $2\cdot 1$ is 2 times 1. In your case the quotient is the abelian group of order $142$ generated by $\le3$ elements. What this group is exactly you can get by reducing the matrix to the triangular form. About the book, there should be a reference in the book you are  reading.